# Do Chi^2 confidence intervals give same results as F-test for variances?

Tags: statistical-inference

If I have two sample variances, and I compute their confidence intervals as $\left[\, \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1,1-\alpha/2}},\ \ 
                            \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{n-1,\alpha/2}} \,\right]$, I could reject the null hypothesis if their confidence intervals do not overlap.

Would I do so if and only if I reject the null hypothesis using the F-test on the same sample variances?

If not what is the difference between the two tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would reject a hypothesis if and only if the hypothesized value is outside of the confidence intervals of the same probability.<sup>[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/what-is-the-difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-hypothesis-testing),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Statistical_hypothesis_testing)</sup>